# dmnorm() function with multiple means

Tags: r, distribution, multidimensional-array

I've been searching the answer but didn't find any information about this function except the [off. R docs](http://127.0.0.1:12958/library/mnormt/html/dmnorm.html).

If i want to calculate the values of 1-dimentional normal distribution in the same x with different means or standard deviations i'll just call

```
dnorm(x, mu, sigma)
```

where mu and sigma will be arrays with desired means and sigmas.
Is there any way to perform same trick with dmnorm function from mnormt module, when x and mu are vectors and sigma is a covariation matrix?

P.S.: Sorry for my English, thanks for answers.

Comment: According to ?dmnorm, you can pass several points(x) and several means(mu). About varcov (variance-covariance matrix) there is written, that it is "a positive definite matrix representing...". So, I do believe you are not allowed to pass several matrixes.

Comment: `mapply` would be the way to go.  How are `mu` and `sigma` to be specified?  As lists of vectors and matrices, respectively, or as matrices and 3-dimensional arrays, respectively?

Comment: They are lists of matrices and vectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R the collections of functions are called "packages". If a function is not vectorized in its parameters, you can pass it one parameter as a vector with `sapply` or as a parallelized set of list with `mapply`. So you should consider the mathematical issue, especially that the 'mean' is no longer a single number but rather a vector, and that sigma (which `dmnorm` is calling 'varcov')is no longer a single number but rather a matrix. The first example in the help page gives you the densities of 21 different x,y,z's and a single mean vector and sigma matrix.

Using that example as a starting point, make a list of 7 x,y,x and 7 varying means and sigmas and then `mapply` it to the first 7 items in the xyz's :

```
 x <- seq(-2,4)
 y <- 2*x+10
 z <- x+cos(y) 
 mu <- c(1,12,2)
Sigma <- matrix(c(1,2,0,2,5,0.5,0,0.5,3), 3, 3) 
lsig <- lapply(seq(-2,4)/10, "+", Sigma);  lmean<-lapply(seq(-2,4)/10, "+",mu)

mapply(dmnorm, x=as.data.frame(t(cbind(x,y,z)[1:7,])), mean=lmean,  varcov=lsig)
#        V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7 
# 6.177e-06 6.365e-04 5.364e-03 3.309e-02 2.205e-02 6.898e-03 1.077e-03
```